# Are there faulty review alerts?

Tags: bug

My last review was more than 25 minutes ago. I keep checking my review queue, which appears empty. Yet, I have three review alerts!

It appears, I cannot add pictures from the iPad.

Edit: my meta review queue appears empty too.

Comment: I marked them as duplicates, which they undoubtedly are, yet I find the answer here much clearer. What could we do? @Em1

Comment: I don't think there's an agreement what's best if question B is a duplicate of A but answer to B is better than to A. You can flag your question for moderator attention and see if they merge the questions. Or you can add a reference from my question to yours. Either in comments, or I'm even fine if you edit the question and add a block "This question has also a great answer [LINK HERE]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The review counter in the topbar shows the total number of *pending review tasks*. You don't necessarily see them when opening the review page, because:

1. You may have already reviewed them, or
2. you may be ineligible to review them (e.g., it's a review of your own post, or a post you flagged, etc.)

Simply put, it's the number of posts that need attention, but not necessarily *your* attention.

This discrepancy was discussed in [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742).

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to flag this as duplicate, but the search does not return that question, just as it did not before posting!